# How can I have a border on every printed page with CSS?

Tags: css

I am creating some HTML and I'd like to add a border to every page. Is that possible with CSS?

Comment: google: [*css add border to printed page*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20add%20border%20to%20printed%20page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
@media print{
    body{
        border: 10px solid red;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it for every page

Comment: I see your predicament. The only way I can think of doing it, is by manually creating boxes (to act as borders) at specific height, then using the css command "page-break-before: always;" to put in page breaks.